# Add an img src to html from JavaScript correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a script that creates an inner element in a HTML `div` element.

It works fine, but I think the way I did it using a string is not the most suitable in JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <div class="chartlyrics">...</div><div class="chartlyrics box" id="powered_by"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Where the "**...**" are is where I created the element.

**Javascript**

`document.getElementsByClassName('chartlyrics')[0].innerHTML = '<img src="img/103-logo.jpg" class="" /><br />Powered by '`

**HTML Result:**

```
<body>
    <div class="chart-container">
        <div class="chartlyrics"><img src="img/103-logo.jpg" class="" /><br />Powered by </div><div class="chartlyrics box" id="powered_by"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

How can I do this but **without using a string** when creating the element in JavaScript?

I tried this but it gives me a syntax error:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('chartlyrics')[0].innerHTML = ''
                        
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('chartlyrics')
  .appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
                            
img.src = "img/103-logo.jpg"
img.class = ""
img.textContent = 'Powered by '
    
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('chartlyrics')[0].innerHTML);
```

**Result:**

`document.getElementsByClassName (...). appendChild is not a function`

Comment: To start, `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the first element of the HTMLCollection and append the `<img>` element to that. Furthermore, store the newly created element in a variable first so you can set properties before appending. To add a line break and text after the image, you can append a newly created `<br>` element and use `.append` to add text.

```
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('chartlyrics')[0];
parent.innerHTML = '';
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "img/103-logo.jpg"
img.setAttribute('class', "")
parent.appendChild(img);
parent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
parent.append('Powered by ');
```

However, finding every single element with a specificied class to obtain only one element is extremely wasteful. You should use `document.querySelector` to obtain the first element matching a selector.

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.chartlyrics');
parent.innerHTML = '';
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "img/103-logo.jpg"
img.setAttribute('class', "")
parent.appendChild(img);
parent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
parent.append('Powered by ');
```

Comment: Result: `<img src="img/103-logo.jpg">` and i wish this: `<img src="img/103-logo.jpg" class="" /><br />Powered by `